# prepared statement not working with and operator

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

I am trying to extract some values from my MS Access Database in java. I am facing difficulties in the following query -

```
PreparedStatement p = c.prepareStatement("select GroupMembers from group_data where GroupName = ? and GroupOwnerID = ?");
p.setString(1,gsel);
p.setInt(2,empid);
```

it gives me an error - too few parameters expected 3

However when i am using -

```
PreparedStatement p = c.prepareStatement("select GroupMembers from group_data where         GroupName = ?");
p.setString(1,gsel);
```

it works just fine.

My table schema is:

```
GroupName    GroupMembers   GroupOwnerID
text         text           number
```

What is the problem with the first query?

this is the stack trace

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few paramet
ers. Expected 3.
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6964)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7121)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecute(JdbcOdbc.java:3156)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcPreparedState
ment.java:215)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcOdbcPrepared
Statement.java:90)
        at ntpc.Sms$1$4$3.actionPerformed(Sms.java:743)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:20
18)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.jav
a:2341)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel
.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259
)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonL
istener.java:252)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832
)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)

        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:242)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.
java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:150)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Does it make sense if you use `p.setString(1,1);
p.setInt(2,1);`? I want to know if `empid` or `gsel` is null

Comment: no they are not null ...  i want to get the resultset based on two constraints ...

Comment: Can you add the whole Stacktrace please and some more code (execution of the statement and get the return parameter)?

Comment: i added the stack trace

Comment: the problem is that i am not able to get values based on two conditions

Comment: The driver might not support `and`. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/171850

Comment: is there any other way to check two constraints

Comment: Try using Jackcess or UCanAccess instead of the Sun JDBC-ODBC bridge driver.

Comment: i am using JDBC - ODBC only

Comment: I just tried your first query and it worked fine for me. Double-check your code against the table definition in Access and make sure that all of your field names match ***exactly*** and your field types are correct.

Comment: may be you have set 3 parameters in the past and now you are passing 2.Just clean the project and re run.Hope this will solve

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this official guide to query an access database http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/examples-of-query-criteria-HA010066611.aspx

Comment: i just tried and the query with and ...  is working with delete option but not select